# Accessing none Monobehaviour class view Photonview

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm trying to set up a function that updates a players sprites/colours based on a class that isn't derived from monobehaviour, but because of this it wont allow me to add it to the photonview.

My game has a class called `PlayerDataClass` that stores all the information for the local player. I haven't set this up as a monobehaviour class as I want to be able to access it without attaching it to a gameobject. However because of this I'm unable to access it with photonview.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better alternative?

I'm currently just logging the name of the `ColorTheme` variable attached to `PlayerDataClass`, but it just logs the local client variable rather than the client who called the function.

PlayerDataClass.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using Photon.Pun;

[Serializable]
public class PlayerDataClass
{
    [SerializeField] private string username;
    [SerializeField] private string colorTheme;
    [SerializeField] private string color1;
    [SerializeField] private string color2;

    public string Username {
        get { return username; }
        set {
            username = value;
            PhotonNetwork.NickName = value;
        }
    }

    public string ColorTheme {
        get { return colorTheme; }
        set { colorTheme = value; }
    }

    public string Color1 {
        get { return color1; }
        set { color1 = value; }
    }

    public string Color2 {
        get { return color2; }
        set { color2 = value; }
    }
}
```

NetworkPlayer.cs

```
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class NetworkPlayer : MonoBehaviourPun
{
    public Vector3 m_NetworkPosition = Vector3.zero;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    public PlayerDataClass m_Player = new PlayerDataClass();

    void Awake()
    {
        // Import scripts
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        if (!photonView.IsMine)
        {
            photonView.RPC("UpdateColor", RpcTarget.AllBuffered, null);
        }
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void UpdateColor()
    {
        Debug.Log("local color name is " + m_Player.ColorTheme);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is sync the `m_Player.ColorTheme` to other clients.

Your `NetworkPlayer` which is the "owner" of the `PlayerDataClass` instance **is** a `MonoBehaviourPun` so you can relay all requried sync calls through it .. like you basically already did with `UpdateColor` ... you just need to pass in a parameter:

```
[PunRPC]
void UpdateColor(string theme)
{
    // Assign the received string
    m_Player.ColorTheme = theme;
    Debug.Log($"local color name is now \"{m_Player.ColorTheme}\"");
}
```

and call it like

```
// instead you should rather do this only if you ARE the owner of this view
// YOU want to tell OTHER users what your color is
if (photonView.IsMine)
{
    // Pass in the string to be synced 
    // Rather use OthersBuffered since you don't want to receive
    // your own call again
    photonView.RPC(nameof(UpdateColor), RpcTarget.OthersBuffered, m_Player.ColorTheme);
}
```

---

You could also consider to make your entire `PlayerDataClass` a photon synchronizable [Custom Type](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-US/realtime/current/reference/serialization-in-photon#custom_types_in_c__35_) and send it over entirely.